# How to close current and previous one activity when user logout from app in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to close both current and previous(parent)activity when user logout from app,
But Here the problem is that when user logout from app then it redirect to login activity to ask user for login, and if user press back button then it redirect to welcome page, how to close current and previous (welcome) page at once when user get logout .

here is my logout code in menu.

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.Logout_secondActivity) {
        session.logoutUser();

        finish();
        //Welcome.this.finish();

        Toast.makeText(Second_activity.this, "Logout...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    } 
}
```

Here is session manager for Logout user!,

```
/**
         * Check login method will check user login status
         * If false it will redirect user to login page
         * Else won't do anything
         * */
        public void checkLogin(){
            // Check login status
            if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
                // if user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                _context.startActivity(i);
            }

        }
```

Here i am already use flags

Comment: where i can write this code? @M.WaqasPervez

Comment: Put answer code after `session.logoutUser()` code

Answer (score 0):

You should start the required activity with `startActivity` after adding these flags. These will clear the activity stack and start the new `Activity` as fresh one. Use your required `Class` name in place of Splash.class and place this code after you logout your user.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Splash.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

**EDIT:**

What i understood from your problem is that you want to go to `HomeActivity` from `LoginActivity` either if it is in activity stack or not. one way you can do this is to override `onBackPressed` in `LoginAcitivty` . i.e when back is pressed in `LoginActivity` it starts the `HomeActivity`. You can do it like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();  // it is optional if you want to keep the login activity in stack you should remove this line
}
```

Comment: It also close home screen , when i press back button from login screen then app is exit, rather than going back home screen.@M.Waqas Pervez

Comment: why should it go back to home screen? Since user logged out. now he cant see home screen unless he re-login.

Comment: you have to use this code in `OnOptionsItemSelected` method. not in your  `checkLogin` method.

Comment: i am using checkLogin code in session manager class, and its working fine for first activity that name is (welcome) if user logout form welcome screen then it is working well, same like if user logout from second screen that name is(second_activity) then login screen open but problem is that on back press it open welcome screen again, i want it should be go on home(main screen) @M.Waqas Pervez

Comment: ok as your own method, what i can be replace on Splash.class? and tell me there is need to remove    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); from CheckLogin Or not.? @M.Waqas Pervez

Comment: try my edited answer. if this doesnt help i dont know what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put shared preferences boolean value from current activity and then always check if a key exist in the parent activity (check it in onPostResume method). If the key exists finish this activity and if not, just remove the key. There might be simpler and more elegant solution but this one will work for sure.

Comment: I Am added session manager for logout user method please see again and tell me what i am missing here@s 1vert

Comment: You asked how to close both activities at once. What I understand is that when a user logs out you want him to leave the whole app. If that's correct when user logs out, just finish current (Welcome) activity and put shared preferences key which you will read in parent (Login) activity.

Comment: no i want no leave hole activity, i try to better understand you about my problem if you have a skype, please contact me on my skype:"sajid.h.glow". because long discussion or chat not allowed here @s1vert

Answer (score 0):

call `finishAffinity();` after `_context.startActivity(i);`

for further reference you may follow this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

**UPDATE:**
if you are calling this function from non Activity class then you must pass the Activity's Context when you call it, like this `_context.finishAffinity()`

Comment: how to call finishAffinity(); it gives error@Nilabja

Comment: It gives that error"The method finishAffinity(Intent) is undefined for the type Context"@Nilaba